# Blender Grids with figures

Tags: units, blenderkit, blender-osm

I'm a beginner at using blender. I have a basic blender grid of 15 x 15 pixels and i want to add attach an image to every pixel. How can I do that ?

I have tried to just stick the images on the grid manually but it's not the good way to go !

P.S. If there's a python scripting way to do this, it should be okay for me too !

What I want to accomplish is this:

I want to make a figure similar to the following one: [image: Grid of 2D images]

What i have successed in doing in blender is a simple grid [image] but i want to attach figures to the pixels of the grid...

P.S. I KNOW HOW TO IMPORT EXTERNAL FIGURES, BUT IT IS NOT CLEAR TO ME HOW I CAN ATTACH EACH FIGURE TO EACH GRID PIXEL.

Hope my answer is clear enough now ! Thank you for your kind help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "attach an image to every pixel" what do you mean? can u add a screenshot or something to demonstrate what u r trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array modifier allows you to repeat an object along an axis. If by "i want to attach figures to the pixels of the grid" you mean that you want to repeatedly place an object at a constant interval then you can use the array modifier. Select the object that you want to repeatedly place in 3D space, go to that object's modifier tab, add an array modifier to it and tweak the array modifier settings until you have what you want. You can use a second array modifier on the same object to repeat the already modified object along another axis in 3D space. [image: array-mods]

Comment: This is exactly what i've been looking for ! Thank you very much.... What I did is that I first imported my images as planes and then followed your array method ! worked very good for me.... Thank you again